# Close the serial connection when tkinter exits

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, serial-port, pyserial

I have initialized a serial connection with an arduino, using

```
ser = serial.Serial(port = COMPort, baudrate=9600, timeout=0.1)
```

However, when i close the application, an LED that is associated with the connection stays open on the arduino. This means the serial connection is still active.

How can i close the serial connection auomatically, when i quit the application?

Comment: You can call the close function after tkinter `mainloop()`.

Comment: Thank you guys. Sorry Cool Cloud, i was busy before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there are two ways to achieve this, one is to place the code below `mainloop()`(as already mentioned by acw1668) and the other is to use `wm_protocol`.

**Method 1:**
Any code after `mainloop()` will be halted as long as the window stays alive, so placing the code after `mainloop()` would execute it after the window is closed.

```
root.mainloop()

ser.close()
```

**Method 2:**
This protocol is triggered when you try to 'delete' the window or close it. So you can bind a function to this and ask it to close the window, then close the connection like:

```
def close():
    root.destroy() # Close the window
    ser.close() # Then the connection

root.wm_protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',close) # Assuming root = Tk()
```